# catkin_make eigen indigo

Tags: catkin-make, eigen, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys!
I have a project in which I've been working on `groovy` and `hydro`. I want to compile the same thing on `indigo` because I had to install ubuntu 14.04 on my computer and I need to use that project. I'm having a problem right now when I'm trying to compile. The error comes from the `FIND_PACKAGE(Eigen REQUIRED)` command.

```
  CMake Error at project/CMakeLists.txt:24 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindEigen.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen", but
  CMake did not find one.
```

I got the idea from http://wiki.ros.org/cmake_modules that it should be the same thing in hydro than in indigo for the eigen module (so I shouldn't have any problems). So I don't know what to do. I'm getting that problem and I know that I have the cmake file needed on `/opt/ros/indigo/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindEigen.cmake`.

Just last thing, I have `libeigen3-dev` installed from the ubuntu repositories, so I'm sure that I shouldn't have any problem because of that.

According to https://github.com/ros/cmake_modules/blob/0.3-devel/README.md I should not have any problem with `FIND_PACKAGE(Eigen REQUIRED)``

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188628/catkin_make-eigen-indigo/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2014-08-01

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer just before finishing my question. So... I forgot to write the dependencies on my `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`

```
   # package.xml
   <build_depend>cmake_modules</build_depend>
   <run_depend>cmake_modules</run_depend> # this line was not described on the website
   # CMakeFiles.txt
   find_package(cmake_modules REQUIRED)
```

This is because I didn't need that before in past versions. If you have any input about that it would be appreciated, even when the question is already answered ;)

---

Originally posted by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) with karma: 649 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 24

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-08-02**:
ooooohhh.... But then that's new only for indigo right? I haven't compiled with hydro with that version yet. But, then if that package is new it shouldn't not work with hydro and groovy if I'm correct. (I'll be checking later also) =)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-08-02**:
cmake_modules 0.2.0 was released to Hydro and Groovy, so you can depend on it. FindEigen.cmake moved there from catkin to cmake_modules 0.3.0 in Indigo. So, I think the identical code will work with Hydro. Let us know if it does not.

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-08-02**:
In hydro I didn't need to `find_package(cmake_modules REQUIRED)` for `Eigen` to work. But well.... I'm happy that it works anyway =)

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-01**:
In fact, the run depend tag is not required. Check [my answer at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018447/using-eigen-library-in-ros-indigo/31141591#31141591) for a more complete answer

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-07-01**:
That answer assumes eigen was already installed. I think that dependency *is* needed for ROS package dependencies to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For this and similar changes see the Indigo migration page: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration#cmake_modules .

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2